# Chrome console + js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Does any one know if it is possible to continuously run a JavaScript in the console window without it stopping when the page gets reloaded.

Here is the script I want to run, all it will do is change the dates and click a button. However when the button is clicked, my script stops. Is there any way around this?

```
var sDate = document.getElementById('START_DATE');
var eDate = document.getElementById('END_DATE');
var btn = document.getElementById('ExcelDataOnly');

var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(0);
d.setDate(1);
d.setFullYear(2012);

function pad(num, size){
    var s = "00" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length-size);
}

for(var i = 1; i < 365; i++){
    var dt = [pad(d.getMonth()+1,2),
    pad(d.getDate(),2),
    d.getFullYear()].join("/");

    console.log("Date:", dt);
    sDate.value = dt;
    eDate.value = dt;
    btn.click();
    while(document.readyState !== "complete") {console.log("Sleeping");};
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
}
```

As you can see from the code, it should do the for loop but it stops after the first round because the page reloads itself.

Comment: As I know, the only way tou can do that is by writing a Chrome extension

Comment: How hard is it do that? All I would need is a button that triggers that snippet of code correct?

Comment: It is not too hard, but depents on your knowledge and your experience. You can read more here : http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html